# How to perform Phonetic and Aproximative search in Lucene.net

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search, solr, lucene.net

When I read the Lucene.net docs, the only analyzer that I find is the standard one. I want to make sure I can do Phonetic or Aproximative search on my index. Is there some extra library I should use on top of Lucene.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try porting one of [Phonetix's analyzers](http://www.tangentum.biz/en/products/phonetix/index.html) (Soundex, Metaphone or DoubleMetaphone)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think Phonetix's Analyzers are written in Java, not in .NET

Comment: @Am: yup, that's why I said "porting". They shouldn't be hard to port anyway, because Lucene.NET is very similar to Lucene Java.